# How to fetch two-level deep @OneToMany association in Spring Data and avoid MultipleBagFetchException

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm still a JPA beginner and would like to know how to best use Spring powerful features to fetch the following simple structure (associations are lazy by default but I have a use case where the whole structure should be loaded without proxies, possibly with the lowest number of SQL queries generated). Simplified entities concerned:

```
@Entity
public class Bundle {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bundle", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
}

...

@Entity
public class Group {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "BUNDLE_ID")
    private Bundle bundle;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();

...

public class Element {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID")
    private Group group;
}
```

My attempt to find all groups and elements under a given bundle (in order to efficiently process them and convert to a DTO later before returning from an endpoint) was to fetch inside `@Query`

```
public interface BundleRepository extends JpaRepository<Bundle, Long> {

@Query("SELECT bundle FROM Bundle bundle "
           + "JOIN FETCH bundle.groups groups "
           + "JOIN FETCH groups.elements "
           + "WHERE bundle.id = :id")
    Optional<Bundle> fetchBundle(@Param("id") long id);
}
```

However, this results in `org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags`. I did some reading on the subject and found that changing `List`s to `Set`s may do the trick, on the other hand some sources discourage from this.

This double `@OneToMany` structure seems very ordinary and multiple `JOIN`s also nothing uncommon but nevertherless I'd like to ask you to point out the right approach. Maybe fetching groups for a bundle separately and then for every group fetching its elements? This would be *1 + number of groups* queries, not a bit wasteful? Please let me know if considering this as a trade-off in this manner is a step in the good direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a. duplicates aren't allowed in the collections, and b. you don't care about the iteration order of the entities in the entity object collections for `groups` and  `elements` (you could still impose ordering when transforming to DTOs using some property of them), then the headline answer is:

1. Yes, change from `List` to a `Set` which communicates both to callers, and to the JPA implementation that duplicates aren't allowed and iteration order can be undefined (which would also solve the bag exception - but at the cost of a gigantic cross-join).
2. To avoid the gigantic cross join that might result from loading both sets at the same time, do the load of the graph in 2 queries (as long as both participate in the same transaction):

```
@Query("SELECT bundle FROM Bundle bundle "
           + "JOIN FETCH bundle.groups groups "
           + "WHERE bundle.id = :id")
    Optional<Bundle> fetchBundle(@Param("id") long id);
}
```

and then a second call to populate the elements on the groups:

```
@Query("SELECT groups FROM Group groups "
           + "JOIN FETCH groups.elements "
           + "WHERE groups.bundle.id = :id")
    Collection<Group> fetchBundleGroups(@Param("id") long id);
}
```

Note that you can in fact ignore the response value of the second call and just do ...

```
Optional<Bundle> maybeBundle = repository.fetchBundle(id);
repository.fetchBundleGroups(id);
// now, maybeBundle.get().groups.elements will all be populated
```

due to a useful feature of the JPA spec, which requires that, within a given JPA EntityManager persistence context scope (usually the same as transaction scope), the same object instance is returned for an entity with the same ID, and thus effects from the second query (to populate the elements on the Group objects) will use the same instances returned from the first query.

Worth noting that the same technique also works if there were to be multiple collections on one of the entities - e.g. `Bundle.authors` - you would just add a 3rd query to populate the authors collection on the Bundle and call that as well to avoid the cross-join between `authors` and `groups`.